# Unable to access a spreadsheet using the Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am having to adapt a new feature on our website from an existing one. The goal is to read a spreadsheet, then update it. I am having issues accessing the information on google spreadsheets using the google spreadsheet API. This is very odd to me, considering I have no problems querying my drive for files and information regarding them, such as mimeType, title, etc.

My oauth2 scope :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

The call I'm trying to make is 1.)

```
$d_data2 = @json_decode(file_get_contents('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1e2jdg1dcCmWhna-zV9ODNNtcgRDi2rGz8xRSsxpcH6c?fields=sheets.properties.title'),true);
```

The code above is ripped and adapted from this pre-existing feature 2.)

```
$post = array(
     "fields" => 'items(id,embedLink,mimeType,title)',
     "supportsAllDrives" => "true",
     "includeItemsFromAllDrives" => "true",
     "access_token" => $_SESSION['g_access_token'],
     "trashed" => "false",
     "q" => "'me' in readers and title contains '22-23 Digital Learning'", // mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
     "pageSize" => "999",
);
$postText = http_build_query($post);

$d_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/?'.$postText),true);
```

When I make the call in #1, all that is returned is null. What are some suggestions or solutions you may have? Any are welcome, please, and thank you.

Comment: What do you see if you echo the contents without trying to decode it as JSON?

Comment: When `json_decode()` returns null, use `echo json_last_error_msg();` to see the reason.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing script of `$d_data2 = @json_decode(file_get_contents('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1e2jdg1dcCmWhna-zV9ODNNtcgRDi2rGz8xRSsxpcH6c?fields=sheets.properties.title'),true);`, in this case, the access token is not used. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

This sample script retrieves the value of `sheets.properties.title` from a Google Spreadsheet.

```php
$accessToken = "###"; // Please set your valid access token.
$post = array(
    "fields" => 'sheets.properties.title',
    "access_token" => $accessToken,
);
$postText = http_build_query($post);
$d_data2 = @json_decode(file_get_contents('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1e2jdg1dcCmWhna-zV9ODNNtcgRDi2rGz8xRSsxpcH6c?' . $postText),true);

foreach ($d_data2["sheets"] as &$sheet) {
    printf("%s\n", $sheet["properties"]["title"]); 
}
```

- When this script is run, all sheet names are shown.

#### Sample script 2:

From `The goal is to read a spreadsheet, then update it.`, in this sample, the sheet name of the 1st tab is changed using Sheets API.

```php
$accessToken = "###"; // Please set your valid access token.
$params = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" . "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken . "\r\n",
        'content' => '{"requests": [{"updateSheetProperties": {"properties": {"title": "sample","index": 0},"fields": "title"}}]}'
    )
);
$d_data2 = file_get_contents('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1e2jdg1dcCmWhna-zV9ODNNtcgRDi2rGz8xRSsxpcH6c:batchUpdate', false, stream_context_create($params));

printf("%s\n", $d_data2);
```

- When this script is run, the sheet name of the 1st tab in Google Spreadsheet is changed to `sample`.

#### Note:

- Please confirm your Spreadsheet ID again.
- When I tested the above 2 scripts, I confirmed that both scripts worked fine. But, if an error occurs, please check whether Sheets API has been enabled at the API console and your access token, your Spreadsheet ID, and, your access token has permission for accessing the Spreadsheet.
- These are the simple sample scripts for explaining to use Sheets API. Please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)